# TabView works only inside the Form and outside not

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to make a window with the selected photos from the pop up window under the text fields, but on pressing the button plus the popup opens in the Form (**Image 2**), as well as displaying all selected photos, also **tabViewStyle** does not work because of this (the application simply crashes after compilation)

**I commented out all stuff what need to know**

[Image 1: Its how looks this ugly window before I pressed + to select photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw8Nh.png)
[Image 2: Popup also inside THIS form...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS7jV.jpg)
[Image 3: There should be a slide mod after the photos are selected, but due to the fact that this is a window in the form it does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31fZN.jpg)

```
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("New Item")) { // NORMAL TEXTFIELDS WHAT I NEED
                TextField("Title", text: $viewModel.singleitem.title)
                TextField("Description", text: $viewModel.singleitem.description)
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Author")) {
                TextField("Author", text: $viewModel.singleitem.author)
            }
            
            if mode == .edit {
                Section {
                    Button("Delete item") { self.presentActionSheet.toggle() }
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
                
                TabView {          // HERE STARTS TABVIEW WITH POPUP AND SELECTED PHOTOS
                    
                    ForEach(pickedImages, id: \.self) { image in
                        
                        GeometryReader { proxy in
                            
                            let size = proxy.size
                            Image(uiImage: image)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
                                .cornerRadius(15)
                            
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    
                }
                .frame(height: 450)
                // MARK: Swift UI Bug
                
                //.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never)) - BUG HERE ALSO TRIED .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: pickedImage.isEmpty ? .never : .always)) - SAME SHT
                .toolbar {
                    Button {

                        showPicker.toggle()

                    } label: {

                        Image(systemName: "plus")

                    }
                }
            
            .popupImagePicker(show: $showPicker) { asset in
                
                // MARK: Need modify
                let manager = PHCachingImageManager.default()
                let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
                options.isSynchronous = true
                
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                    asset.forEach { asset in
                        
                        manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: .init(), contentMode: .default, options: options) { image, _ in
                            
                            guard let image = image else { return }
                         
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                
                                self.pickedImages.append(image)
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
         }
        
        
        
 //       .navigationBarItems(leading: cancelButton, trailing: saveButton)
        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: `TabView appears inside the Form instead outside`, well put the `TabView` outside the `Form`  to start with.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I tried all similar solutions, too obvious not to try, outside the `Form` - `TabView` does not appear at all, I changed question title to a more suitable

Comment: A SwittUI tabview only works reliably at the top, not inside a NavigationView. ou have to create your own.

Comment: @loremipsum I think I understand what you mean, I'll try to do it, thanks <3